# Set MySQL to return numbers as numbers

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, types

Using Codeigniter, any numeric data returned from my MySQL database is returned as strings. How can I configure the database/PHP/Codeigniter to return numbers as numbers?

Comment: Not quite. We need some practical stuff.

Comment: Are you asking for some example code?

Comment: There's some interesting discussion of the PHP-database-queries-always-return-results-as-strings issue at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/110393/. That's from more than 2½ years ago, though, so there may be a cleaner solution now.

Comment: Simple thing just accept the data of type `string` from MySql and then convert them into your type unless it's not absolutely necessary. Why are you looking for the only way to do so?

Comment: Because getting things returned as the type you stored them is a reasonable thing to want as a default behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't just Codeigniter behaviour, it's the behaviour of PHP generally.

If you look at any of the result functions such as [`mysql_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) or [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to name a couple, they return string or an array of strings respectively.

The Codeigniter MySQL drivers use these functions to return their results.